# importing support classes used by Service modules?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular if I have a service, and that service delivers an instance of a class defined elsewhere, do all consumers of the service need to have two imports, or can both the service and the object it provides be imported from the service definition?
For example

Foo.ts:

```
export class Foo {
  ...
}
```

FooProviderService.ts

```
import { Foo } from './Foo'
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FooProviderService {
    constructor(){}
    createFoo(name : string) : Foo {
        return new Foo(name);
    }
}
```

my question is, if I have a component which uses the FooProviderService, is there a way to import Foo's definition from the FooProviderService import rather than having to have two import statements?

The motivation, I have on several occassions created a support class inside the file which defines a service, and then decided I need to extract it into its own separate file.  At that point, I have to go through all the code in every component which uses the service change the imports to get the support class from the new file, instead of from the service import statement.

i.e. is there any way to retain the original import definition in consumers of the service, `import {FooProviderService, Foo} from '../foo_provider_service.ts` even if Foo is defined in a separate file, rather than having to pull out Foo and give it own import statement.

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather focused on the TypeScript language rather than Angular the web framework.

In typescript you can use types implicitly without importing them:

```js
// file1.ts
export interface A {
  prop1: string
}
export function createA(): A {
  return { prop1: 'Hello World!' }
}

// file2.ts
import { createA } from './file1'

const obj = createA()

// OK even if I didn't import the interface explicitly
obj.prop1
```

This works fine as long as you use the type implicitly inside a function body. As soon as you need to annotate something else like a method parameter or a property from a class you're going to need to import said interface.

Another thing that can work out for you is using [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

Utility types let you dynamically define types based on other types. Specifically I think you might find useful the [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) type of a function.

```js
function createA(): A {
    return { prop1: 'hello '}
}
type AA = ReturnType<typeof createA>
```

Which you can perform similar mapping based on class functions too:

```js
class Sample {
    getA(): A {
        return { prop1: 'hello '}
    }
}
const s = new Sample()
type AA = ReturnType<typeof s.getA> // AA is equivalent to A
```